# For which $ \alpha >0 $ the integral $\int _0^3\:\frac{x}{\left(9-x^2\right)^{\alpha }}dx$ converges?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Good evening to everyone. I have a problem and I don't know where to strat from. I have to find for  which $ \alpha >0 $ the integral $$\int _0^3\:\frac{x}{\left(9-x^2\right)^{\alpha }}dx$$ converges. Can someone help me whith this? Thanks for any possible response.

Comment: If $u=9-x^2$ then $\dfrac {-1} 2\,du = x\,dx$ and as $x$ goes from $0$ to $3$, then $u$ goes from $9$ to $0$.  I'd start there. $\qquad$

Comment: Calculate $I_{\epsilon}=\int_0^{3-\epsilon} f(x)\,dx$. You will get an explicit expression, and you will be able to find the $\alpha$ for which $I_{\epsilon}$ has a limit as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:  write it as follows you will see $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 3 } \: \frac { x }{ \left( 9-x^{ 2 } \right) ^{ \alpha  } } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \int _{ 0 }^{ 3 } \: \frac { d\left( 9-{ x }^{ 2 } \right)  }{ \left( 9-x^{ 2 } \right) ^{ \alpha  } } ={ \frac { \left( 9-x^{ 2 } \right) ^{ -\alpha +1 } }{ -2\alpha +2 }  }_{ 0 }^{ 3 }=-\frac { 9^{ -\alpha +1 } }{ -2\alpha +2 } $$

Answer (score 3):

For $\alpha\geq1$, the integral definitely does not converge.

For $\alpha<1$, the integral converges. Your problem mentions that $\alpha>0$ so the interval for $\alpha$ is $(0,1)$

To show this, make a substitution with $u=9-x^2$.

You should arrive at the conclusion that 
$$\int_0^3\frac{x}{(9-x^2)^\alpha}=\frac{9^{1-\alpha}}{2-2a}$$